# Do I need to worry about memory corruption if I DON'T use atomic functions in opencl?

Tags: opencl, atomic

I have a kernel where for each execution I might write a result into an output Array. 
All the `LowerValues[]` will be initialised to a magic number to see if it has been untouched.
I don't care which value is in `LowerValues[N]`, as long as it's valid.

```
kernel void HasLower( global int* Values, global int* LowerValues )
{
    int ThisIndex = get_global_id(0);
    int Max = get_global_size(0);
    int ThisValue = Values[Index];

    for ( int ThatIndex=ThisIndex+1;    ThatIndex<Max;  ThatIndex++ )
    {
        int ThatValue = Values[ThatIndex];
        if ( ThatValue < ThisValue )
        {
            LowerValues[ThisValue] = ThatValue;
        }
        else if ( ThatValue > ThisValue )
        {
            LowerValues[ThatValue] = ThisValue;
        }
    }
}
```

My multithread head says, use an atomic function to set the value in `LowerValues[]` so the memory does not get corrupted when two threads write to the same memory location.

But.... what I'm wondering is, do I NEED to use atomic functions? 
I don't care if one execution overwrites another, but I don't want corrupted values. Is this something I need to be concerned about with opencl? is it driver/device dependent? 
I couldn't find any information regards to this and so far haven't come across any memory corruption when I omit atomics.

I could play it safe, but perhaps there are optimisations to be had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not *need* to use atomic functions as basic operations on basic types have so side effects in memory. However, as you've already guessed, multiple threads will find that their ThisValue < Values[idx] and LowerValues[ThatValue] has to be considered a random, non-repeatable choice of true answers.

Comment: Is this just common/logical knowledge or do you have a citation? (I couldn't find any mention of it in docs/google)
And do you know if this changes if the output were a struct?

Comment: Just experience. I also tried looking it up once but ultimately decided to have the answer be derived from nvidia's PTX-specification only. Apart from that: Your kernel will most probably have some performance issues because the warps diverge when they take different paths on the < and > conditions. Lookup the examples on sorting in OpenCL (or CUDA) because that's what it seems you are doing after all; after sorting, the answer can just be read from the array.

Comment: This is just a very simplified example :) it's a KIND of sorting,  establishing the best (lowest error) object in a set of 1000 after finding which ones match. I won't need to iterate over the output when finished, just use it for some verification. LowestValue[x] definitely is lowest if the magic number remains. I probably should look at the sorting examples anyway :)

Comment: Accepting this unless someone comes up with a contradictory answer or some explicit verification